Attribute HAL Explorer - Spring Boot
In Spring Boot, the 'password' attribute doesn't appear in the HAL explorer due to the @Transient and @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY) annotations. I'd like the 'password' to appear in the POST form so I don't have to remember all the attributes since there are several services.

@Entity
@Table(name = "organizations")
@Data
public class Organization {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private UUID id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Name is mandatory")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,16}$",
            message = "Name must contain 3 to 16 characters and can only contain letters, numbers, underscores, and hyphens")
    private String name;

    @NotBlank(message = "OrgCode is mandatory")
    private String orgCode;

    @NotBlank(message = "Eac is mandatory")
    private String eac;

    @NotBlank(message = "Country is mandatory")
    private String country;

    @NotBlank(message = "Password is mandatory")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$",
            message = "Password must be at least 8 characters long and contain at least one lowercase letter, one uppercase letter, one digit, and one special character")
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    @Transient
    private String password;

}

I'm using Spring Data Rest.
@RepositoryRestResource
interface MetricRepository extends JpaRepository<Metric, UUID> {}

I already tried following the steps below.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/reference/representations.html
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/reference/customizing/custom-jackson-deserialization.html
I'd like to retrieve the 'password' attribute in the HAL explorer within the form.

Spring data rest doesn't support this configuration. If you press F12 in the browser, refresh HAL explorer page, look at the network request. There is a GET request with media type JSON schema which doesn't contain the password because your annotation. The HAL explorer is generated based on this JSON schema.

@yejianfengblue First of all, thank you for the response. I understand that HAL Explorer makes an HTTP request with the Accept schema+json, and the attribute is not present there. Is there any possibility of serializing that attribute to the schema?

I don't think it possible. The json schema is generated from the "read" view, that is, the response of a GET request. The @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY) makes the password not readable. You can still put the password in the request body when you test the API with postman.

This is the commit about skipping non-Jackson-serializable properties from being rendered in the schema.  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/commit/25aee4be1c7691daab9d9502a07acad07fec676d

By the way, @Transient should be useless here. Look at the annotation javadoc. It marks the property or field not persistent.
